# Jira login with Google authentication

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I have created a plugin, by which I have a google login button on **/login.jsp** and **/secure/Dashboard.jspa** 's login gadget.

Everything is working good on **/login.jsp** but Google API is not loading on **/dashboard.jspa**.
In my .js:-

```
 AJS.$(function() {
    var po = document.createElement("script"); 
    po.type = "text/javascript"; 
    po.async = true;
    po.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js";
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; 
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
});

gapi.auth.signIn({
        callback: gPSignInCallback,
        clientid: CLIENT_ID,
        cookiepolicy: "single_host_origin",
        approvalprompt: "force",
        requestvisibleactions: "http://schema.org/AddAction",
        scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login email"
    })
```

on **/dashboard.jspa** page **gapi.auth is undefine** is throwing on console.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define 'auth' object first and initialize it with **gapi.auth2.init()** call.

Here is the example to define auth2 object:

```
var auth2="";
var onGoogleLoad = function () {
    gapi.load('auth2', function () {
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: 'YOUR CLIENT ID',
    })
    enableGoogleButton()
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Deepak, Got some solution but still  getting an error "RPC: request rejected (bad origin): https://accounts.google.com"